# How to get python to 'except' each line of code within a chunk, rather than as a whole?

Tags: python, list, try-catch

I've been working on some python code, and messed around with lists to create a matrix and have been working on a way of filling elements and those surrounding those elements with values. I encountered the 'index out of range errors' as if I loop through each element and reach the far side of the matrix, and try add further, it falls out of the list. Despite it being bad practice I decided to use the "try...except..pass" method so that my code looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMYCF.png

The issue is however, once it passes one error, it returns straight to the start of the loop and fails to add the remaining values to the surrounding elements. Is there a way to get the "try" command to apply individually to each command or does it have to be to each line individually?

Comment: Please include code as text, in your question, rather than as a blurry screenshot on an external site.

Comment: The code is quite long so it doesn't make sense to post it all here, but I can post it in an online notepad: https://shrib.com/?v=nc#u6cIIQbnX8Bc5kV1S36K

Comment: Read [mcve] in the help. You don't want to post your whole program here, but you should be able to strip it down to a much smaller program that demonstrates the problem you're asking about, and then post _that_ here.

Comment: As a side note, this code would probably be a lot simpler (and more efficient, to boot) using a numpy array instead of a list of lists. That's not a trivial rewrite, and it may not be appropriate here, but if you hadn't thought of it, it's worth thinking of—and if you've never heard of numpy, and have a bit of time, it may be worth going through the quick start tutorial.

Comment: There has to be a more efficient way to do this.. In any case, the answer to your question is no: you cannot enforce execution of all statements within a try block. Once an error is encountered, the Python interpreter moves to the except block. Now, if you store the indices of the 2D list you want incremented and have a variable representing the value by which they should be incremented, you could iterate over the list and use a try-except for each element.

Comment: @eicksl The more efficient way would almost certainly start with reorganizing things around numpy. To start with, you can just make all of the A, B, and D updates into 5x5 arrays and just `self.w[i0-2:i0+3, j0-2:j0+3] += self.Aupdate` (plus either truncating the edges or padding them). Replacing the inner loop and leaving the outer ones alone may already be enough. If not, they're just a partial matrix multiplication between `self.m=='A'` and `Aupdate`, and the same for `B` and `D`. Or maybe you just take the existing code and run it in PyPy or `@numba.jit` it and it's good enough. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you usually want in cases like this is a wrapper function.

For example, you have a bunch of lines that look like this:

```
self.w[i0-1][j0+1] += 3
```

The only difference from one line to the next is the two indices and the increment value. So, let's write a method that takes those three things as parameters:

```
def _inc(self, i, j, diff):
    try:
        self.w[i][j] += diff
    except:
        pass
```

And now, each of those lines can be changed to:

```
self._inc(i0-1, j0+1, 3)
```

… and it'll do what you wanted: increment everything that doesn't raise an exception, do nothing when it does.

But, while we're at it, you probably don't want a bare `except` here. Instead, you want to guard against just the specific exception you were expecting. Which is probably an `IndexError`.

The nice thing about a wrapper function is that we only have to change things in one place instead of 78 places:

```
def _inc(self, i, j, diff):
    try:
        self.w[i][j] += diff
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

And likewise, if you wanted to change things so it calls `log.debug` every time there's an exception, you just replace that `pass`.

Or if you want to pre-check or post-check that `0 <= i < len(self.w) and 0 <= j < len(self.w[i])`. (And you may want this—notice that if `self.w` is a list of lists, when `i0` is 0, `i0-1` is `-1`, which isn't going to raise an `IndexError`, it's going to increment the last row…)